# TemplateBinding in Xamarin.Froms not working

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, templatebinding

I tried [this simple example](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/template-binding/) from the official Xamarin page, that contains a template binding like:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TealTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.HeaderText}" />
    <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.FooterText}" />
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However, i always get ths error by just copying the example code to Visual Studio.:

[image]

Can anyone give me a short example how to bind from within a ControlTemplate to a property of the templated control, be it of the binding context *or* the control itself?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked out the issue with 'Parent'. But for my project I use:

```
{TemplateBinding BindingContext.IsBusy}
```

IN the page that use ControlTemplate, I also use a ViewModel and binding this ViewModel, which has IsBusy property, to the page.